# postgres index: single or multi column. only where or also in case

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

My main query is like:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE status = 1 AND lang = %s AND inactive = 0 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN location <> NULL THEN location <-> %s ELSE RANDOM () END LIMIT 1;
```

All other queries I do in the code often are where "user_id" that is a primary key, so I don't think they need particular attention about index.

In a case like this, is it better to create an index multicolumn like (status, lang, inactive) or a index in any column so I can use a condition in index (status = 1, inactive = 0 etc).

In case the index should be multicolumn do I also have to include location?

- location is in case, not in where
- location already uses a gist index because it's a geography column type

Also while lang and inactive are not often updated, status in continuosly updated because it represent the availability for the user to be matched to another user.

that table does not have index, only primary key on user_id.

so to sum up:

- is it better a single column or multi column index?
- in case of multi column, should location be included since it is in case and not in where and it aleady use a gist index?
- in general, if a condition is in case instead of where, is index used and usefull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best index for this query:

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users u
WHERE u.status = 1 AND lang = %s AND inactive = 0
ORDER BY CASE WHEN location <> NULL THEN location <-> %s ELSE RANDOM () END
LIMIT 1;
```

is a covering index on `status, inactive, lang, location, user_id)`.  However, the last two columns are only being used to fetch values from the index.  Your query still needs to do the sort for the `order by`.

Comment: So I include also location despite it already has an index created using gist? I don't get why including also user_id if it is a column primary key. Thanks

Comment: @user8372336 . . . It may not be needed, but I like to include it to be explicit.

Comment: may i ask you why you use in the query where (status, lang, inactive) and in the index order you inverted lang with inactive (stauts, inactive, lang, location, user_id). does the index work anyway?

Comment: @user8372336 . . . The order of the first three columns doesn't matter, because all are equality.   There was no reason to change the order.